# Generate random number that fluctuates by F within range R

Tags: javascript, random

I want to generate a random number within this range: `[0.79, 2.7]`

Every time I generate a number I want to store its value so that next time I generate a new number its **absolute** difference (compared to the previous one) is never greater than 0.01.

What I'm trying to simulate is the fluctuation of the value of a cryptocoin in 0.01 steps

I have come up with this method:

```
const MIN = 0.79
const MAX = 2.7
const DIFF = 0.01
const INTERVAL = 1000

let previous = undefined 

function getRandom() {
  let current = Math.random() * (MAX - MIN) + MIN;
    
  if (Math.abs(current - (previous || current)) > DIFF){
    return getRandom()
  } else {
    previous = current
    return current
  }
}

setInterval(() => {
  console.log(getRandom())
}, INTERVAL)
```

It works, as in, the `MIN`, `MAX` and `DIFF` restrictions are applied. However, the values I get seem to always fluctuate around the very first random number that will be generated. So if the first random number I get is e.g. `2.34` I will then start getting:

```
2.338268500646769
2.3415300555082035
2.3438416874302623
2.3475220779731107
2.3552742162452693
2.353575076772505
2.3502457929806693
2.3561300642858143
2.353045875361622
2.3592926605489004
2.360013424409005
2.3520769942926023
```

Whereas, what I want is for them to fluctuate all the way from 0.79 to 2.7 with 0.01 steps but randomly nevertheless.  So the value of a cryptocoin might start going up for a X seconds, then down for Y seconds, then further down for another Z seconds then all of a sudden up for T seconds etc..

Can you think of an algorithm to mimic that ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: There's certainly no standard language feature to do that.

Comment: Generate an initial value and then just "flip a coin" (random number > 0.5 = heads, < 0.5 = tails) and add or subtract `0.01`

Comment: Yes! It was so simple, thanks :)

Comment: If you want to add your comment as an answer I will accept it otherwise I will close the OP. :)

Comment: Feel free to add it yourself. Imho that's not enough for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Andreas's comment, the following works just fine:

```
const MIN = 0.79
const MAX = 2.7
const DIFF = 0.01

let previous = Math.random() * (MAX - MIN) + MIN

function getRandom() {
  let current = Math.random() < 0.5 ? previous + DIFF : previous - DIFF

  if (current < MIN) {
    current = MIN
  } else if (current > MAX) {
    current = MAX
  }

  previous = current

  return current
}

setInterval(() => {
  console.log(getRandom())
}, 100)
```